# Why are Vulkan command buffers still "alive" after being submitted to the gpu?

Tags: vulkan

The Vulkan tutorial that I'm working through (https://vkguide.dev/docs/chapter-1/vulkan_command_flow/) states: "Once a command buffer has been submitted, it’s still “alive”, and being consumed by the GPU, at this point it is NOT safe to reset the command buffer yet."
I had assumed that resetting the command buffer would be fine after submitting it, thinking that the data was now safely over on the gpu (and that the command buffer itself lives on the cpu). Is the issue that the actual transfer of data doesn't occur as soon as vkQueueSubmit is called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Thinking that the data was now safely over on the gpu (and that the command buffer itself lives on the cpu).

This is a somewhat "old fashioned" way of thinking.

Most (all?) modern hardware can directly share memory between the CPU and GPU to some extent, although there are some platform-dependent limitations.

On most mobile and integrated graphics platforms there is no such thing thing as dedicated graphics memory - the CPU and GPU are just sharing the same system RAM. Even on discrete graphics cards there is normally a way to access a subset of the system RAM directly from the GPU over PCIe.

Vulkan is designed to exploit this - there is no point wasting memory and CPU cycles creating copies you don't actually need. Resources in Vulkan are assumed to be directly referenced by the GPU, and you can't delete them until the are not longer referenced by a queued command.

Comment: Thank you; I had no idea that a discrete gpu could directly access system RAM. Can I ask why the way memory works in Vulkan feels so obscure? I haven't used any other graphics APIs, but I'd assumed that a big part of programming for the gpu would be about specifying exactly when you wanted things to be sent over to the gpu, and that if there were parts of system memory that the gpu could access directly, then you'd have to specifically check that that was the case and choose what to store there etc.

Comment: The standard has to be flexible enough to efficiently cope with hardware from multiple vendors, and on top of that discrete vs integrated vs mobile all have different tradeoffs.

For bulk data (images, buffers) the application can use the memory allocation flags determine where things can be stored, and what properties that memory needs to have in terms of CPU and GPU visibility. 

For control plane (queues, command buffers, and descriptors) this is opaque as it's assumed that the driver will handle this in the best way possible for the hardware in that device.

Answer (score 4):

The right term is "pending". When you submit a command buffer it goes to the "pending" state.

This is what the spec says:

> Queue submission of a command buffer changes the state of a command
> buffer from the executable state to the pending state. Whilst in the
> pending state, applications must not attempt to modify the command
> buffer in any way - as the device may be processing the commands
> recorded to it. Once execution of a command buffer completes, the
> command buffer either reverts back to the executable state, or if it
> was recorded with VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_USAGE_ONE_TIME_SUBMIT_BIT, it
> moves to the invalid state. A synchronization command should be used
> to detect when this occurs.

You can only reset a command buffer when it's in one of the following states:

- **Recording**: yes, it's possible to reset before calling vkEndCommandBuffer.
- **Executable**: right after vkEndCommandBuffer or after the execution has completed.
- **Invalid**: when a resource used by the command buffer has been destroyed.

You can read about the whole command buffer lifecycle here (there is a handy diagram):

https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/chap6.html#commandbuffers-lifecycle